# exponential sum of primes

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Fix $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$. I would like to know a reference that shows $$\mathbb{E}_{n\leq N} \Lambda(n) e^{2\pi i \alpha n} \to 0,$$ as $N$ tends to infinity.

I am familiar with Vinagradov's estimate, which seemingly does not directly imply this.

Comment: Two good references for this result are Chapter 13 of Iwaniec and Kowalski's book "Analytic Number Theory," (Thm. 13.6) and recent course notes by Tao, https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/03/30/254a-notes-8-the-hardy-littlewood-circle-method-and-vinogradovs-theorem/ (combine Prop 18 and 24).

Comment: @BradRodgers Many thanks for your response. Proposition 24 in Tao's notes was exactly what I was looking for: since $\alpha$ is irrational, one can assume that $q \geq C$ for any $C \geq 1$ and get savings from the $\phi(q)$. In Iwaniec/Kowalski, there is an annoying $log(x)^3$ which prevents one from obtaining the result in the case where $\alpha$ is close to a rational with tiny denominator infinitely often (perhaps something like the Louisville number).

Comment: This gives a nice major arc (Proposition 24)/minor arc (Vinagradov's estimate proof). Also in Tao's notes, he mentions that in Helfgott's proof of ternary Goldbach he eliminates the extra logs from Proposition 18, which seems very nontrivial.

Comment: Ah, I didn't pay sufficient attention to the $(\log x)^3$, but you're absolutely right.